# Printing out spreadsheet data

Tags: python, windows, printing, python-3.9

I want to print some data from spreadsheet. I decided to use python. How can I call out a "Print preview"? For example like this:

[image: screenshot]

I tried something like this:

```
os.startfile('test.txt', 'print')
```

but it doesn't make a print preview.

I am using Python 3.9.

Answer (score 3):

Use this (tested on Windows 10):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['notepad', '/p', "test.txt"])
```

On Linux use:

```
import os
os.system("lp text.txt")
```

As to previewing the file on screen, just use print function. If you want graphics use tkinter or any other graphics library (PyQt, etc)